# Compiler error with generic Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor

I've defined a custom `select` component in Blazor like this:

```cs
public class BetterInputSelect<TItem> : InputBase<TItem>
{
  [Parameter]
  public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; } = new List<TItem>();

  protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.OpenElement(0, "select");
    builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
    builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);
    builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", BindConverter.FormatValue(CurrentValueAsString));
    builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string>(
      this, value => CurrentValueAsString = value, CurrentValueAsString!, null));

    foreach (var item in this.Data)
    {
      builder.OpenElement(5, "option");
      builder.AddAttribute(6, "value", item!.ToString());
      builder.AddContent(7, this.FindDisplayName(item));
      builder.CloseElement();
    }

    builder.CloseElement();
  }

  protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, out TItem result, out string validationErrorMessage)
  {
    // Check for enums first.
    if (typeof(TItem).IsEnum && BindConverter.TryConvertTo(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out TItem? parsedValue))
    {
      result = parsedValue!;
      validationErrorMessage = null!;
      return true;
    }

    // Other types here
    // ...

    result = default!;
    validationErrorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is not valid.";
    return false;
  }

  private string FindDisplayName(TItem value)
  {
    return value switch
    {
      null => string.Empty,
      Enum @enum => @enum.GetDescription(),
      _ => value.ToString() ?? string.Empty
    };
  }
}
```

which can then be used like this:

```html
<BetterInputSelect Data="@Reasons" @bind-Value="@Reason" />
```

where `Reasons` and `Reason` are defined like this:

```cs
public SomeReason Reason { get; set; }

private IEnumerable<SomeReason>? Reasons { get; set; }

...

public enum SomeReason 
{
  ...
}
```

This works great as long as the value that is bound by `@bind-Value` is not nullable. When I do:

```cs
public SomeReason? Reason { get; set; }
```

I get a compile time error:

```
[CS0411] The type arguments for method 
'TypeInference.CreateBetterInputSelect_0<TItem>(RenderTreeBuilder, int, int, IEnumerable<TItem>, int, TItem, int, EventCallback<TItem>, int, Expression<Func<TItem>>)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Can I simply not bind to a nullable property, or is there a way to make the compiler happy that I've missed?

#### EDIT

And if I try to define the type explicitly like this:

```html
<BetterInputSelect
  Data="@Reasons" 
  @bind-Value="@Reason" 
  TItem="SomeReason" />
```

then I get the following compiler errors:

```
[CS1503] Argument 1: cannot convert from 'SomeReason?' to 'SomeReason'
[CS1503] Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<SomeReason?>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'
[CS0266] Cannot implicitly convert type 'SomeReason?' to 'SomeReason'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
[CS1662] Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this worked with non-nullable value. Types can't be inferred even from constructor parameters or property assignments, where the parameter type is known at compile time. You should specify the type of the `TItem` property explicitly

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to define it explicitly in the `<BetterInputSelect ...` tag, but couldn't find the correct syntax.

Comment: @BartKiers what syntax did you try?  It should be something like `TItem="SomeReason"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @KirkWoll, I updated my question with the result of using `TItem="SomeReason"`

Comment: not sure buh, did u try @bind-Value="@Reason??somevalue"

Comment: try this:: <BetterInputSelect Data="@Reasons" @bind-Value="@Reason" TItem="SomeReason?" />  (SomeReason? instead of SomeReason)

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty  sure I tried `TItem="SomeReason?"`, but I've shut down my dev machine: will try tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @DamilolaAdegunwa that was indeed part of the solution: many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was as follows:

In `BetterInputSelect<TItem>`:

```cs
// Was:
//   [Parameter]
//   public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; } = new List<TItem>();

[Parameter]
public IEnumerable<TItem?> Data { get; set; } = new List<TItem?>();
```

and in the view I did:

```html
<BetterInputSelect
  Data="@(Reasons as IEnumerable<SomeReason?>)" 
  TItem="SomeReason?"
  @bind-Value="@Reason" />
```

which works when `@Reason` is nullable- and non-nullable. The non-nullable would of course not need a cast and explicit type definition:

```html
<BetterInputSelect
  Data="@Reasons" 
  @bind-Value="@Reason" />
```

Comment: Just wonder what is better in your component than the built-in InputSelect. I'm of the opinion that it degrades rather than elevates when you pass IEnumerable<TItem> to the custom component instead of using ChildContent...

Comment: The built-in InputSelect can (AFAIK) only hold enums and strings. It only displays the value of enums (where I want to extract custom descriptions from enums, and other objects).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with Net7 / Net8, `@(Reasons as IEnumerable<SomeReason?>)` doesn't work anymore. I have done this a bit differently now:

**Parameters:**

```cs
[Parameter]
[EditorRequired]
public List<TItem?> Items { get; set; } = new();

[Parameter]
public TItem? SelectedValue { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<TItem?> SelectedValueChanged { get; set; }

protected async Task OnSelectedValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Value is not string value)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        await this.SelectedValueChanged.InvokeAsync((TItem)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(TItem)));
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignored
    }
}
```

**Razor:**

```
<select value="@this.SelectedValue" @onchange="@this.OnSelectedValueChanged" @key="@this.Items">
</select>
```

**Usage (Razor):**

```
<MyComponent Items="@this.Items" @bind-SelectedValue="@this.SelectedItem" />
```

**Usage (C#):**

```cs
protected List<SomeEnum?> Items { get; set; } = new();

protected SomeEnum? SelectedItem { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    this.Items = ((SomeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum))).Select(t => (SomeEnum?)t).ToList();
}

public Enum SomeEnum
{
    One,
    Two
}
```

If you have set `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` and `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` in your project, you probably need to ignore `CS8669` by adding it to `<NoWarn>CS8669</NoWarn>`... (Seems like Visual Studio doesn't know that the nullable context should be enabled for razor syntax things as well)...